# How to create another table from join query

Tags: mysql-workbench

I ran this query to inner join two tables:

```
select * from order_details od
    left join menu_items mi
    on od.item_id=mi.menu_item_id;
```

I want to store the result data into another table using this query

```
select * into new_table 
    from order_details od
    left join menu_items mi
    on od.item_id=mi.menu_item_id;
```

But getting an error code 1327, Undeclared variable: new_table

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to [tag:mysql-workbench] itself? Would it work better when running in another tool? Also, shouldn't you use `SELECT ... INTO` with a variable rather than a plain table name?

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with mysql but in oracle it would be

insert into new_table
select *
from order_details od
left join menu_items mi
on od.item_id=mi.menu_item_id;

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO new_table (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT od.column1, mi.column2, mi.column3, ...
FROM order_details od
LEFT JOIN menu_items mi ON od.item_id = mi.menu_item_id;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?